# What is the difference between `GvNAME` and `GvENAME`?

Tags: perl, perl-xs, perlapi

In perl sources `GvNAME` and `GvENAME`. Both return name for given `gv`. But second stands for effective name.

Dumping names I have not seen the difference.

May someone clear what is the difference and provide example which shows it?

**UPD**
Because this is related to naming too. What is difference between `HvNAME` vs `HvNAME_HEK`

Answer (score 1):

The "effective" means who create this `gv`.

For example your module `Module::` define `my_sub`. Then this sub was imported into `Main::`. 
So the sub name is `Main::my_sub` but effective name is `Module::my_sub`